# Converting Json Object array Values to a single array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, autocomplete

Good day

I am trying to use an autocomplete jquery framework.. buy my problem is how can i get my objects either from a json file or just a quick typed json object like the below and get all the Object.values(arry) to a single array like below..

> ["samue", "anthon", "Harmony", "Johnson"]

and must be an array.. because auto complete frameworks only works with arrays

```
const myobj = [
    {
      "name": "samuel",
      "surname": "anthony"
    },
    {
      "name": "Harmony",
      "surname": "Johnson"
    }
  ]

  const file = "json/user.json";

  fetch('file')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then((data) =>{
      let i = 0;
      const val = Object.values(data[i]);
      if(i < data.length){
        i++;
        const all = Object.values(data[i]);
        console.log(all);
      }

      var input = document.getElementById("countries");
      var awesomplete = new Awesomplete(input, {
          minChars: 1,
          maxItems: 5,
          autoFirst: true
      });
      awesomplete.list = val;

      //wanted array of
      //["samuel", "anthon", "school"]
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

To convert `myObj` to your desired array you can use [`.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) like so:

```js
const myobj = [{
    "name": "samuel",
    "surname": "anthony"
  },
  {
    "name": "Harmony",
    "surname": "Johnson"
  }
];

const res = myobj.flatMap(Object.values);
console.log(res);
```

However, do note. `flatMap` is not available in all browsers and so it doesn't have the best browser compatibility.

If you cannot use `.flatMap` you can use [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [destructing assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) as an alternative:

```js
const myobj = [{
    "name": "samuel",
    "surname": "anthony"
  },
  {
    "name": "Harmony",
    "surname": "Johnson"
  }
];

const res = myobj.reduce((acc, {name, surname}) => [...acc, name, surname], []);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `reduce`

```js
const myobj = [
    {
      "name": "samuel",
      "surname": "anthony"
    },
    {
      "name": "Harmony",
      "surname": "Johnson"
    }
  ]
  console.log(myobj.reduce((acc,e)=>{acc.push(e.name);acc.push(e.surname);return acc},[]))
```

Using `forEach`

```js
const myobj = [
    {
      "name": "samuel",
      "surname": "anthony"
    },
    {
      "name": "Harmony",
      "surname": "Johnson"
    }
  ]

var a=[];
myobj.forEach((e)=>{a.push(e.name);a.push(e.surname)})
console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `push()` Object.values(obj) into desire array using `...` spread operator

```js
const myobj = [
    {
      "name": "samuel",
      "surname": "anthony"
    },
    {
      "name": "Harmony",
      "surname": "Johnson"
    }
  ]
let arr = []
myobj.forEach(obj=> arr.push(...Object.values(obj)));
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Array.map() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

An example use case might be:

```
const oldArr = [
    {
      "name": "Samuel",
      "surname": "anthony"
    },
    {
      "name": "Harmony",
      "surname": "Johnson"
    }
 ]

const newArr = oldArr.map(x => x.name) // ['Samuel', 'Harmony']
```

Answer (score 0):

The Flatten Object:

```js
const myobj = [{
"name": "samuel",
"surname": "anthony"
  },
  {
"name": "Harmony",
"surname": "Johnson"
  }
];

var flatten=myobj.reduce((arr, v)=> [...arr,...[v.name,v.surname]],[]);
console.log(flatten);
```